# How to use both ScrollView and full size for an image?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to show my selected image in full screen, which works absolutely fine on a phone but, on a tablet, the image does not cover the screen. I am using `boxFit.cover`, so I'm not sure why it is not covering the screen.

One solution is to use `height: double.infinity` and `width: double.infinity`. Then the tablet screen is covered. However, if I do that, I have to remove my "SingleChildScrollView" which means that I can't scroll pictures that are wider, when needed.

Here is my code:

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(widget.imPath),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Is there any workaround so that I can both cover my screen and scroll when needed?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from your tablet?

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot was redundant as it did not show *any* UI. It is *just a **full screen*** image, there is not anything to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I want to point out that you will not be able to scroll with your current setup. See, you have exactly one widget that covers exactly the area that is available to the scroll view.
I will just assume that you plan on *adding other widgets to the `SingleChildScrollView`* but have the image take up the whole screen or available height.

I have two solutions. One of them covers the whole screen and is a little bit easier because of that and the other one is more robust and also accounts for padding or a scenario where you do not have the full screen for the image.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: constraints.biggest.height,
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(widget.imPath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ), 
    ),
  );
}
```

In this possible solution, I added a [`LayoutBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) before the `SingleChildScrollView` and then use the biggest height constraints to surround the `Image` with a `SizedBox` that uses that height.

The simpler solution that **only works in a full screen scenario** uses the height from the [`MediaQuery`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(widget.imPath),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ), 
    ),
  );
}
```